# How to bring partial text Bold in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, textbox

I have one textbox which has the following text.

```
TextBox1.Text = "The above materials will be delivered at Site. One copy of the Delivery Challan / Invoice to be send to Head Office."
```

In that, I want to make the following text "One copy of the Delivery Challan / Invoice to be send to Head Office" as in Capital Letters and also in Bold.

I tried the following coding:

```
TextBox1.Font.Bold = true;
```

But it made all the text as bold. How do I make it?

Comment: try using a richbox, this box has more functionalitie when formatting text

Comment: For such manipulations you would need a RichTextBox won't be possible with the regular TextBox

Comment: take a look at http://forums.asp.net/t/1434379.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a web application, you can't use the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) component.

Instead, you can use a `LiteralControl` inside a `span` or a `div`.

i.e:

```
.aspx
<div runat="server" id="div1"></div>

.cs
div1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("this is normal text, "));
div1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<b>And the rest of the sentence is bold</b>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just distributing data and not allowing the user to edit the value I would suggest using a  combo(or div span your choice) using Styles.  It requires absolutely no server side code for example

```
<div id="normaltext" name="normaltext" class="textbox">
    <div id="boldtext" name="boldtext" class="textbox" style="font-weight:bold"></div>

</div>
```

You can then access either portion using javascript to getElementsById.

Alternatively if it isn't an HTML based object I would argue to use two labels instead of a textbox.  One could be bold and the other normal.

Answer (score -2):

Put two textbox instead of one. In windows forms it's the only way. in Wpf, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263055/wpf-making-part-of-the-text-bold).

Comment: Instead of downvoting, specify the technology you're using.

Comment: That's not correct. under windows forms you can use the RichTextBox component.