# WPF component to explain how to use application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am building **WPF/C#** application with **Visual Studio 2010**. 
I have a guide window which should contain only text fields which explain how to use my application.

I am not sure which WPF GUI component is best for this purpose. 
Is it **Label**, **TextBox** or some other?

Yes I want it to be multi-line.

> **Note:** I wasn't able to find **TextBlock** component in the Toolbox
>   panel.

Comment: Maybe a RichTextBox with IsReadOnly property set to true? (if you want more formatting option)

Comment: You are using designer for WPF? Designer is the worst place to use as it adds margins and names to the components that you add. Names and margins have a little place in WinForms but we have moved on now. Create xaml by hand, it is not difficult and it will make it easier for you. BTW TextBlock supports multiline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting text in a TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263055/formatting-text-in-a-textblock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a TextBlock or a RichTextBox, both is perfectly fine. But RichTextBox gives you the possibility to display rich formatted text.

If you cannot find a control in the Toolbox, you can directly edit the xaml code.

Comment: Yes RichTextBox did the job.