# TextBlock Text property was bound to a source, can I format the text display?

Tags: wpf

I have a `TextBlock` object with a bound `Text` property.

I cannot control the binding source, but I can change `Binding` and `TextBlock`.

I want to format some key word display style...

---

For example:

I want to formart word "key" to bold, and formart word "RED" to red color,

And source data is "Example keyword and RED word".

After formatting, the equivalent Xaml should be

```
Example <Bold>key</Bold>word and <Span Foreground="Red">RED</Span> word
```

Of course, if the source was changed, Text must also changing synchronously.

What should I do?

Comment: you should go with richtextbox. TextBlock not support text formating as you want.

Comment: If your source data like 'Example keyword and RED word' then how you will decide which text is red and which text is bold ?

Comment: @maulikkansara I can change `TextBlock`, but I can't replace it

Comment: @AnantDabhi text "key" to bold and text "RED" to red, that's I want to know...

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextBlock.inlines like below-

```
<TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="Key" />
    <Run Foreground="Red" Text="Red" />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
```

You can also use binding for Text property in inlines.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263055/formatting-text-in-a-textblock) example.

Comment: Oh, you said I should move the `Binding` for `Text` to `Inlines`? I'll try it

Comment: I meant if you have different properties in code then you can use binding in inlines otherwise you are good to go with hardcoded texts if 'Key', 'Red' are fixed to be styled.

Comment: I can't confirm what text will in the Source, so I can't hard code