# How to make text bold in WPF TextBox in my case?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my model I have such property

```
...
public string LastClipFrame
{
    get
    {
        var result = MCConstants.DEFAULT;

        if (_LastClipFrame != MCConstants.DEFAULT_LAST_CLIP_FRAME)
        {
            return _LastClipFrame.ToString();
        }
        else if (IsLastFrameClipInFocus)
        {
            result = string.Empty;
            IsLastFrameClipInFocus = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            _LastClipFrame = MCConstants.DEFAULT_LAST_CLIP_FRAME;
        }
        else if (!value.Contains("-") && int.TryParse(value, out int tmpVal))
        {
            _LastClipFrame = tmpVal;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

...
```

And I use it in my `.xaml`

```
...
<TextBox x:Name="Tb_last_clip_frame"
         Grid.Column="0"
         GotFocus="Tb_last_clip_frame_GotFocus"
         LostFocus="Tb_last_clip_frame_LostFocus"
         Text="{Binding Path=LastClipFrame, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Margin="5,5,0,5" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
...
```

Now I would like to add one `if` condition like if `LastClipFrame = "default"`, so do nothing, but if is isn't (like any other word), so make this word **bold**

How to do it?

I found a lot of ways how to make color, how to make specific word how to make anything you want, but nothing about just how to `textbox.setBold(true)`... or something like this.

**EDIT**

```
#region Assembly PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\PresentationCore.dll
#endregion

using System.ComponentModel;

namespace System.Windows
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Refers to the density of a typeface, in terms of the lightness or heaviness of
    //     the strokes.
    [Localizability(LocalizationCategory.None)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontWeightConverter))]
    public struct FontWeight : IFormattable
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Compares two instances of System.Windows.FontWeight.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   left:
        //     The first System.Windows.FontWeight object to compare.
        //
        //   right:
        //     The second System.Windows.FontWeight object to compare.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     An System.Int32 value that indicates the relationship between the two instances
        //     of System.Windows.FontWeight. When the return value is less than zero, left is
        //     less than right. When this value is zero, it indicates that both operands are
        //     equal. When the value is greater than zero, it indicates that left is greater
        //     than right.
        public static int Compare(FontWeight left, FontWeight right);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a new instance of System.Windows.FontWeight that corresponds to the OpenType
        //     usWeightClass value.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   weightValue:
        //     An integer value between 1 and 999 that corresponds to the usWeightClass definition
        //     in the OpenType specification.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A new instance of System.Windows.FontWeight.
        public static FontWeight FromOpenTypeWeight(int weightValue);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Determines whether the current System.Windows.FontWeight object is equal to a
        //     specified System.Windows.FontWeight object.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   obj:
        //     The instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare for equality.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the two instances are equal; otherwise, false.
        public bool Equals(FontWeight obj);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Determines whether the current System.Windows.FontWeight object is equal to a
        //     specified object.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   obj:
        //     The System.Object to compare for equality.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the two instances are equal; otherwise, false.
        public override bool Equals(object obj);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Retrieves the hash code for this object.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A 32-bit hash code, which is a signed integer.
        public override int GetHashCode();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns a value that represents the OpenType usWeightClass for the System.Windows.FontWeight
        //     object.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     An integer value between 1 and 999 that corresponds to the usWeightClass definition
        //     in the OpenType specification.
        public int ToOpenTypeWeight();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns a text string that represents the value of the System.Windows.FontWeight
        //     object and is based on the System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property
        //     information.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A System.String that represents the value of the System.Windows.FontWeight object,
        //     such as "Light", "Normal", or "UltraBold".
        public override string ToString();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Compares two instances of System.Windows.FontWeight for equality.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   left:
        //     The first instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        //   right:
        //     The second instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the instances of System.Windows.FontWeight are equal; otherwise, false.
        public static bool operator ==(FontWeight left, FontWeight right);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Evaluates two instances of System.Windows.FontWeight to determine inequality.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   left:
        //     The first instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        //   right:
        //     The second instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     false if left is equal to right; otherwise, true.
        public static bool operator !=(FontWeight left, FontWeight right);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Evaluates two instances of System.Windows.FontWeight to determine whether one
        //     instance is less than the other.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   left:
        //     The first instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        //   right:
        //     The second instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if left is less than right; otherwise, false.
        public static bool operator <(FontWeight left, FontWeight right);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Evaluates two instances of System.Windows.FontWeight to determine whether one
        //     instance is greater than the other.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   left:
        //     The first instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        //   right:
        //     The second instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if left is greater than right; otherwise, false.
        public static bool operator >(FontWeight left, FontWeight right);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Evaluates two instances of System.Windows.FontWeight to determine whether one
        //     instance is less than or equal to the other.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   left:
        //     The first instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        //   right:
        //     The second instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if left is less than or equal to right; otherwise, false.
        public static bool operator <=(FontWeight left, FontWeight right);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Evaluates two instances of System.Windows.FontWeight to determine whether one
        //     instance is greater than or equal to the other.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   left:
        //     The first instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        //   right:
        //     The second instance of System.Windows.FontWeight to compare.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if left is greater than or equal to right; otherwise, false.
        public static bool operator >=(FontWeight left, FontWeight right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263055/formatting-text-in-a-textblock) help you?

Comment: @germi I saw it, but almost all examples there about `.xalm` imlementation. Or do you mean specific answer?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24452321/1344058) and the one below it contain examples on how to do that in code.

Comment: In code behind of view you could do `Tb_last_clip_frame.SetValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeight.Bold)`.

Comment: @Sinatr I don't know why but, I don't have this `TextBlock.FontWeightProperty` and this `FontWeight.Bold` values

Comment: `using System.Windows; using System.Windows.Controls;`

Comment: @Sinatr edited my question, take a look there is no `FontWeight.Bold` value

Comment: [There is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.fontweights), I miss **s** in name: `FontWeights.Bold`.