# How to change foreground color of partial string inside DataGrid cell in WPF？

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Here is **my MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Helloone.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Helloone"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DG1" Margin="0,100,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="text1" Binding="{Binding Onedata}" Width="150"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="text2" Binding="{Binding Twodata}" Width="150"/>
                
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Helloone
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<MyCell> listaaa = new List<MyCell>();
            listaaa.Add(new MyCell() { Onedata="abc", Twodata ="def"});
            listaaa.Add(new MyCell() { Onedata="ghj", Twodata ="yougood"});
            DG1.ItemsSource= listaaa;
        }
    }

    public class MyCell
    {
        public string? Onedata { get; set; }
        public string? Twodata { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**It looks like this after running**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45xf7.png)

**I want to change the color of some strings in one of the cells and make them bold. For example, the "good" in the string "yougood" in the second row and second column is set to red and bold, while the color of "you" remains the same unchanged, the effect after running is like the picture below**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRAl3.jpg)

**Since my native language is not english, I am having a hard time searching, kind people please help me**

Comment: i think its no possible with TextBox, see RichTextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TextBlock` to format text inline. Check out this: [Formatting text in a TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263055/formatting-text-in-a-textblock).

Code behind:

```cs
private Run GetGoodRun()
{
    return new Run("good")
    {
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    };
}

private void FormatText(TextBlock tb, string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || !text.Contains("good"))
        return;

    var tokens = text.Split("good");
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        tb.Inlines.Add(tokens[i]);
        tb.Inlines.Add(GetGoodRun());
    }

    tb.Inlines.Add(tokens.LastOrDefault());
}

private void TextBlock_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FormatText(sender as TextBlock, (e.NewValue as MyCell)?.Twodata);
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="text2"
                        Width="150">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Twodata}"
                       DataContextChanged="TextBlock_DataContextChanged" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need the information where the red and bold part is inside the string.
After that you can use a TextBlock and a DataTempalte to show the parts of the string.
The string is split in three parts. The red part, the part before and after red.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string redpart = "good";
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<MyCell> listaaa = new List<MyCell>();
            listaaa.Add(new MyCell() { Onedata = "abc", Twodata = "def" });
            listaaa.Add(new MyCell() { Onedata = "ghj", Twodata = "yougood" });
            listaaa.Add(new MyCell() { Onedata = "lmn", Twodata = "goodbye" });
            DG1.ItemsSource = listaaa;

            foreach (var cell in listaaa)
            {
                if (cell.Twodata != null)
                {
                    int index = cell.Twodata.IndexOf(redpart);
                    if (index >= 0)
                    {
                        cell.TwodataBeforeRedPart = cell.Twodata.Substring(0, index);
                        cell.TwodataRedPart = cell.Twodata.Substring(index, redpart.Length);
                        cell.TwodataAfterRedPart = cell.Twodata.Substring(index + redpart.Length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.TwodataBeforeRedPart = cell.Twodata;
                        cell.TwodataRedPart = "";
                        cell.TwodataAfterRedPart = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I added the property to MyCell but you could handle it somewhere else too.

```
   public class MyCell
   {
       public string? Onedata { get; set; }
       public string? Twodata { get; set; }
       public string TwodataBeforeRedPart { get; set; }
       public string TwodataRedPart { get; set; }
       public string TwodataAfterRedPart { get; set; }
   }
```

Here is the updated Grid

```
  <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DG1" Margin="0,100,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="text1" Binding="{Binding Onedata}" Width="150"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="text2">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Run Text="{Binding TwodataBeforeRedPart}" />
                                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding TwodataRedPart}" />
                                <Run Text="{Binding TwodataAfterRedPart}" />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I am very happy that you can answer my question. I tried your code and it really works. Using your method, if there are two identical "good" in a cell, how to modify MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs What about the code?